# Formating Date and Time in specific case on Android

Tags: java, android, string, date, datetime

I've searched a lot, but nothing seams to help me... I have built a string out of many resources that in the end looks like this (I have used some substring methods and things like that):

```
xxxa="16.Aug.2012 07:15:00"
```

and I want to parse it into date so I can compare it with current time. So, I use those lines:

```
Date datex=null;
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.Mmm.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
try {
            datex = (Date)formatter.parse(xxxa);
            //Log.w("TIME: ", datex.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

From my point of view, those 2 things match and should be parsed normaly.. or should it?

I always get an error like this:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16.Aug.2012 07:00:00" at Java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626) ........
```

I've tried to change positions of letters, to change where something will be.. but still does not fit. I can change that string to look like anything... I just want it to look like a real time, so I can compare time now and that time...

Anyone ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> **M** Month in year
>
> **m** Minute in hour

```
 String dateStr = "16.Aug.2012 07:15:00";
        Date datex = null;
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        try {
            datex = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
            System.out.println(datex);
            //Log.w("TIME: ", datex.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Ty Man! People like you are the reason why the Earth still rotates..

Comment: @Igx33: That is too much man. I am just sharing what I learned.